# Do i need to learn Artificial intelligence before learning Heuristics

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I am planning to do one project on  Meta heuristics based on planning and scheduling.
But i have not yet studies Artificial intelligence subjects. I have studies neural networks subjects. I want to know that can i start straight with Meta Heuristics books and tutorials 
or i need to know Artificial intelligence before diving into meta heuristics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  I took a class on Intelligent Algorithms (simulated annealing, boids, particle swarm, genetic algorithms, neural networks) with no AI background.

Comment: NP.  This was my favorite course in college.  It's pretty fun stuff that I don't get to use day-to-day.